# create a mortgage calculator with html slider that sum other variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

i have a question.

I need to create a mortgage calculator but it's particulary complex because i need to sum others variable to the mortgage payment.
Please see the WIP website that i'm making: [link](http://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/home-configurator/checkout-prova.php?tipo=A.3&stile=contemporary&allestimento=silver).

As you can see, i have a mortgage payment, and some "plus" in the checkboxes.
Basically I have 3 problems:

1. I don't know why my mortgage payment starts with NaN, but i need to start with a precise number (maybe the max mortgage payment) as you can see is you use the sliders and put the first to the max
2. After you use the slider, and you click on one of the checkboxes, the price of the checkboxes doesn't sum to the mortgage payment but it will erase it. i need that the checkboxes and the mortgage payment sums to each others.
3. As it possible to make the  slider values `min` and `max` as percentages? Like this:`<input type="range" min="20%" max="80%" value="" step="5000" onchange="showAmount2(this.value)" id="slider1">`?

Here a clean code to check:

```js
//checkboxes-price
var basicPrice = 0; // This is how we start
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', getCheck);

function getCheck() {
  var currentPrice = basicPrice; // every time
  CurrentPrice = basicPrice,
    plus = [],
    total = 0;
  console.log(currentPrice)
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, el) {

    if ($(el).is(":checked")) {

      total += parseInt($(el).val());
      console.log(total);
      // UPDATE:
      plus.push($(el).data('name')); // get the label text
    }
  });

  $("#plus-display").html(plus.join(", "));
  $('#rata-display-2').html(total);
  $('#rata-display-1').html(total);
}


//slider
$(document).ready(function() {


  var zzz = document.getElementById('aaa').innerText;
  document.getElementById('slider1').max = zzz;
});
const $mutuo = $("#mutuo"),
  $rata = $("#rata-display-2"),
  $anni = $("#anni"),
  $slider1 = $("#slider1"),
  $slider2 = $("#slider2"),
  $max = $("#aaa").html();


function showAmount1(newAmount) {
  document.getElementById('mutuo').innerHTML = newAmount;
  $mutuo.val($("#mutuo").innerHTML);
  update();
}


function showAmount2(newAmount) {

  document.getElementById('anni').innerHTML = newAmount;
  $anni.val($("#anni").innerHTML);
  update();
}



function update() {
  let interesseannuo = 1.60,
    C = $mutuo.html(),
    anni = $anni.html(),
    i = interesseannuo / 12 / 100,
    n = anni * 12,
    rata = C * i / (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n));

  $rata.html(rata.toFixed(0) + " €");
}
update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="aaa" class="span text-sottotitolo_dimensione _2 rata checkout">100000</span><br> <br><br>
<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">PLUS:<strong>place in which display the name of the checkboxes</strong></div><br><br><br>
<form id="plus" name="plus" data-name="plus" class="form-5">
  <div class="plus-wrapper interior-pack w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="interior-pack" name="interior-pack" data-name="interior-pack" value="25" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="interior-pack" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Interior Pack<br></strong>+25 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper domotica w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="domotica" name="domotica" data-name="domotica" value="7" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="domotica" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Sicurezza Domotica<br>‍</strong>+7 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper security w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="security-plus" name="security-plus" data-name="security-plus" value="9" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Security Plus<br>‍</strong>+9 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper emotion w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="emotion" name="emotion" data-name="emotion" value="15" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="emotion" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Emotion<br>‍‍</strong>+15 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper box-auto w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="box-auto" name="box-auto" data-name="box-auto" value="123" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Box Auto<br>‍‍</strong>+123 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper assicurazione w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="assicurazione" name="assicurazione" data-name="assicurazione" value="4" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="assicurazione" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Assicurazione<br>‍</strong>+4 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper wellness w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="wellness" name="wellness" data-name="wellness" value="45" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="wellness" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Wellness<br>‍‍</strong>+45 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper outdoor w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="outdoor" name="outdoor" data-name="outdoor" value="36" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="outdoor" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Outdoor Pack<br>‍</strong>+36 € al mese</label></div>
</form><br><br><br>
<div class="text-ckeckout_wrapper">
  <div class="text-checkout color">SCEGLI <span class="bold text-span-4">L&#x27;IMPORTO</span> DEL MUTUO:</div>
  <div class="slider w-embed"><input type="range" min="0" max="" value="" step="10000" onchange="showAmount1(this.value)" id="slider1"></div>
  <div id="mutuo" class="text-checkout color bold">20%</div>
</div>
<div class="lineetta checkout"></div>
<div class="text-ckeckout_wrapper">
  <div class="text-checkout color">SCEGLI <span class="bold text-span-5">LA DURATA</span> DEL MUTUO:</div>
  <div class="slider w-embed"><input type="range" min="10" max="30" value="20" step="5" onchange="showAmount2(this.value)" id="slider1"></div>
  <div id="anni" value="10" class="text-checkout color bold">10</div>
</div><br><br><br>
<span id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">0 €</span><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Please fix all console errors too. You have error on `form-rata, anni, mutuo` - why mix jQuery  and DOM by the way?

Comment: And there should nt be a comma after `$rata.html(rata.toFixed(0) + " €"),`

Comment: hi @mplungjan, thanks, I have fixed the errors and the comma. I have mixed JQuery and DOM because i'm really not into Javascript.. it's actually my first complex project and I'm really new in this world.
Need a little bit of experience here, but my boss asked me this job and  needed to find workarounds..

Comment: Please see the latest version of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Several things

1. Do not use commas with let and const - if you have globals, initialise them in the on ready - notice I call update there too now
2. Make sure your values are not strings ( +string will cast to number if string is a number)
3. Use $ consistently
4. user .text() and not .val for containers, val is for input fields
5. I am not sure what you were doing with this code - very bad mix of dom and val and innerHTML
6. duplicate IDs on the sliders

```
function showAmount1(newAmount) {
   document.getElementById('mutuo').innerHTML = newAmount;
   $mutuo.val($("#mutuo").innerHTML);
   update();
}
```

Here is an improved version

```js
var $mutuo,$rata,$anni,$slider1,$slider2,$max; // set this globally if you use it globally

//checkboxes-price
var basicPrice = 0; // This is how we start
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', getCheck);

function getCheck() {
  var currentPrice = basicPrice, // every time
    plus = [],
    total = 0;

  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
      total += parseInt($(el).val());
      console.log(total);
      // UPDATE:
      plus.push($(el).data('name')); // get the label text
    }
  });

  $("#plus-display").html(plus.join(", "));
  $rata.text(total);
  $('#rata-display-1').html(total);
}


//slider
$(document).ready(function() {
  var zzz = parseInt($('#aaa').text());
  $('#slider1').attr("max", zzz);
  $mutuo = $("#mutuo");
  $rata = $("#rata-display-2");
  $anni = $("#anni");
  $slider1 = $("#slider1");
  $slider2 = $("#slider2");
  $max = $("#aaa").html();
  update();
  $(".slider").on("change",function() {
    update();
    $mutuo.text($("#slider1").val());
    $anni.text($("#slider2").val());
  })
});



function update() {
  let interesseannuo = 1.60;
  let C = +$mutuo.text() ||0;
  let anni = +$anni.text() || 0
  let i = interesseannuo / 12 / 100;
  let n = anni * 12;
  let rata = C * i / (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n));
  $rata.html(rata.toFixed(0) + " €");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="aaa" class="span text-sottotitolo_dimensione _2 rata checkout">100000</span><br> <br><br>
<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">PLUS:<strong>place in which display the name of the checkboxes</strong></div><br><br><br>
<form id="plus" name="plus" data-name="plus" class="form-5">
  <div class="plus-wrapper interior-pack w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="interior-pack" name="interior-pack" data-name="interior-pack" value="25" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="interior-pack" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Interior Pack<br></strong>+25 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper domotica w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="domotica" name="domotica" data-name="domotica" value="7" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="domotica" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Sicurezza Domotica<br>‍</strong>+7 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper security w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="security-plus" name="security-plus" data-name="security-plus" value="9" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Security Plus<br>‍</strong>+9 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper emotion w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="emotion" name="emotion" data-name="emotion" value="15" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="emotion" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Emotion<br>‍‍</strong>+15 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper box-auto w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="box-auto" name="box-auto" data-name="box-auto" value="123" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Box Auto<br>‍‍</strong>+123 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper assicurazione w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="assicurazione" name="assicurazione" data-name="assicurazione" value="4" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="assicurazione" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Assicurazione<br>‍</strong>+4 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper wellness w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="wellness" name="wellness" data-name="wellness" value="45" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="wellness" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Wellness<br>‍‍</strong>+45 € al mese</label></div>
  <div class="plus-wrapper outdoor w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="outdoor" name="outdoor" data-name="outdoor" value="36" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="outdoor" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Outdoor Pack<br>‍</strong>+36 € al mese</label></div>
</form><br><br><br>
<div class="text-ckeckout_wrapper">
  <div class="text-checkout color">SCEGLI <span class="bold text-span-4">L&#x27;IMPORTO</span> DEL MUTUO:</div>
  <div class="slider w-embed"><input type="range" min="0" max="" value="" step="10000" id="slider1"></div>
  <div id="mutuo" class="text-checkout color bold">20%</div>
</div>
<div class="lineetta checkout"></div>
<div class="text-ckeckout_wrapper">
  <div class="text-checkout color">SCEGLI <span class="bold text-span-5">LA DURATA</span> DEL MUTUO:</div>
  <div class="slider w-embed"><input type="range" min="10" max="30" value="20" step="5" id="slider2"></div>
  <div id="anni" value="10" class="text-checkout color bold">10</div>
</div><br><br><br>
<span id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">0 €</span><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Hi, the version I've uploaded on my [website](http://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/home-configurator/checkout-prova.php?tipo=A.3&stile=contemporary&allestimento=silver) before your last version of the answer work better because i don't have to move the slider with  `id="anni"` to change the price..
Many thanks, I hope you can help me with the two other questions:
1. when I click on the checkboxes, the price will erase the mortgage and i need to sum the checkboxes to the mortgage payment.. is this possible?

Comment: You can have percentage - just multiply by value/100